# CakePHP user control

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

So i have two models

clients

employees

The main difference between these two are that employees has some different more advanced controls.

Now regardless of what user that logs in i need to set a cookie (what the cookie does doesnt matter just to give you an idea).

Now since my employees has more options and actions than clients there is a seperate index view for the.

Now to my question since both types of users has to set a cookie is it possible to do this from the client login controller meaning that "unknown person tries to log in" -> "checks client model if user exists" if not "check employees controler if user exists" if true -> "set cookie " ->"go to employee view index"

Is this possible and is it a good way to do it. Note that the reason why i need to do this is because i want to create a God like user in the clients table. My client table consists of alot of joins and it would be easier to create a "God like" user that will look the same as a normal client (kind of like a proxy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’ve gone about this the wrong way.

Ideally, you should have a `users` table and a corresponding `User` model, and then use ACL to determine what a user can and can’t do. You can create roles for clients and employees, and set permissions on these groups, and assign each user to a group.

If you have client- and employee-specific data you wish to store, then you can always create these tables/models and set them to belong to a User.

Comment: this is actually exactly what i have done. Clients been made using ACL however a new request has been made to make employees because of this one id in our client table is right now the "admin id" and all i need to do when i log in is to collect this static id or even better set it when creating a new employee the only real questio is can i redirect to another view afterwards?

Comment: It’s not what you’ve done if you have two separate models. The ACL should designate whether a User is a client or an employee; not the model itself. Using ACL, you can restrict access to one group entirely if you wanted to.

Comment: i just got corrected by my boss we are not using ACL yet but it is a good idea to set it up

Comment: Don't use ACL if you don't need it. It's a huge overhead in all directions. Maybe you can use sth simpler like [tinyauth](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/).

Comment: Sorry for that. I will try to be more verbose.

Comment: I’d say ACL is *perfect* for this situation. He has different levels of users who should have different levels of access. It’s exactly the scenario ACL solves.